# Jinja2: saying 'Render this macro inside another macro or template'

Tags: python, templates, macros, jinja2

I have a number of macros I'd like to render within a common container macro or template. With pseudo-code:

Macro1

Macro2

Macro3

Container

In a template:

```
"render macro1 inside of Container" e.g. {{ macro1 with Container }}
```

I don't want to go through rendering Container and then the macro inside it everytime, I just need to specify, when this macro, enclose with this other macro

I think 'call' (http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) is what I'm looking for but I don't quite understand it right now. Any input, and how I can clarify this if it is not clear appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
{% macro _enclosure() %}
    <div id="topenclosure">hello I'm on top</div>
        {{ caller() }}
    <div id="bottomenclosure">hello I'm on the bottom</div>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro account_user_profile_macro(i) %}
    {% call _enclosure() %}
        {{i.__dict__}}
    {% endcall %} 
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: seems not work for me :-(

```
{% call host(_host) %}
TypeError: macro 'host' was invoked with two values for the special caller argument.  This is most likely a bug.
```

Comment: https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/678#issuecomment-277043879  I solved by put `caller()` into each macro.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#call):

In some cases it can be useful to pass a macro to another macro. For this purpose, you can use the special call block. The following example shows a macro that takes advantage of the call functionality and how it can be used:

```
{% macro render_dialog(title, class='dialog') -%}
    <div class="{{ class }}">
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <div class="contents">
            {{ caller() }}
        </div>
    </div>
{%- endmacro %}

{% call render_dialog('Hello World') %}
    This is a simple dialog rendered by using a macro and
    a call block.
{% endcall %}
```